# What does "couldn't have cared less" mean?

Tags: meaning

I look up the dictionary that it means `It doesn't matter to me` for `couldn't care less` . However, I can't get `*couldn't have cared less*` Thanks.

A: How long have you been divorced?

B: Two years since it's been final, but it hadn't been good for years.
Honestly, we stuck it out for the kids, `who couldn't have cared less`.

Comment: What do you think it means? This is an extremely common expression, and it means your capacity for caring about a thing is at the minimum level, below which you are incapable of caring. It is another way of saying you don't care about that thing at all.

Comment: Robusto - Does it mean, We don't care about the kids?

Comment: What does "who" imply??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one says that they couldn't care less, they are essentially saying 'I really don't care!' or 'I don't want to know.'

For example,

> Person A: 'I got a better mark than you for the English essay.'
>
> Person B: 'I couldn't care less!'

Comment: Dog Lover - Actually I'm confused after adding "have" in the sentence , "who couldn't have cared less". We (parents) have no time to take care of the kids?

Comment: "Have" simply puts the saying into the past tense. "I couldn't care less" = "I couldn't have cared less". What your example says is that the **kids** didn't really care that the parents 'stuck out the divorce'; it didn't really mean anything to them.